# Logic Help needed

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

This code works only once, i.e if the user comes online and goes offline. I want to loop in such a way that it keeps providing me information always. Such as: Online 11:00, Offline 11:30, Online 11:45, Offline 12:00.

How would I fix that?

```
bool showed =false;
bool nshowd =false;                         
for (; ; )
{
    //chech_online() <- this methods gives true if the person is online on FB

    bool check_online =check_online();                             

    if(check_online ==true && !showed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Online !!" +DateTime.Now);
        showed = true;
    } 
    else if(check_online ==false && !nshowd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OFFline !!" + DateTime.Now);
        nshowd = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a loop and sleep for ten minutes each iteration etc?

```
bool toggle = false;
bool exitloop = false;
int checkinterval = 600; // time in seconds between check

while(!exitloop)
{
    bool is_online = check_online();                             

    if (is_online) 
    {
        if (!toggle) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Online!" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            toggle = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (toggle) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Offline!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            toggle = false;
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(checkinterval * 1000);

    // it would be a good idea to allow a mechanism
    // to exit from the infinite loop.
    if (check_if_we_should_exit_loop()) 
    {
        exitloop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't show that the user has logged on/off _again_, as the `showed`/`nshowd` variables are never reset

Comment: See update. Logic has changed, there is no need to have two different booleans.

Answer (score 2):

Why are `showed` and `nshowed` different variables? Don't you want a single `is_online` variable then testif that's different to `check_online`?

```
bool is_online = false;
for(;;)
{
    bool check_online = check_online();
    if (check_online != is_online)
    {
        // Online state has changed. Store the new state and log out
        is_online = check_online;
        if (is_online)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Online !!" +DateTime.Now);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Offline !!" +DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution behaves differently depending on the user being logged on or off at program startup. If the user is online, it shows `Online !![program startup time]`, otherwise it doesn't show anything. To make this consistent, I'd use a nullable bool initialized to null instead (so that at startup every state is different from the initial value) ;)

Comment: Yes, true - good spot. I think in practice you probably wouldn't care about logging if they're offline at program start up but I don't know precisely what the OP needs.

Comment: It'd also be a good way to distinguish between _something has gone wrong_ and _the user is actually offline_, especially if exceptions are handled silently

Answer (score 1):

Since `showed` and `nshowd` are mutually exclusive, there's no point in maintaining them both - that's the whole point of Boolean variables:

```
userShown = false
while true:
    userOnline = check_online()
    if userOnline && !userShown:
        output "User is online"
        userShown = true
    else:
        if !userOnline && userShown:
            output "User is offline"
            userShown = false
    sleep a bit
```

Alternatively, you can just maintain the last state and only display when it changes:

```
isOnline = check_online()
wasOnline = !isOnline
while true:
    if isOnline != wasOnline:
        output "User is ", (isOnline) ? "online" : "offline"
        wasOnline = isOnline
    sleep a bit
    isOnline = check_online()
```

This particular method guarantees the output of an initial message reagardless of the user's state.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool status = false;
        bool statusChange = false;
        while (true)
        {
            if (IsOnline())
            {
                if (status == false && statusChange == false)
                    statusChange = status = true;
                else if (status == false && statusChange == true)
                    status = true;
                else if (status == true && statusChange == false) ;
                else if (status == true && statusChange == true)
                    statusChange = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (status == false && statusChange == false) ;
                else if (status == false && statusChange == true)
                    status = statusChange = false;
                else if (status == true && statusChange == false)
                {
                    status = false;
                    statusChange = true;
                }
                else if (status == true && statusChange == true)
                    statusChange = false;
            }
            if (statusChange)
            {
                UpdateStaus(status);
                statusChange= false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That `while` loop can be shortened to `while (true) { bool isOnline = IsOnline(); if (status != isOnline) { UpdateStatus(status = isOnline); } }`, which is slightly more readable...